# Python 3, range().append() returns error: 'range' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, append, range

In Python 2.7 the following works without a problem:

```
myrange = range(10,100,10)
myrange.append(200)
print(my range)
```

Output: [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,200]

Conversely, in Python 3.3.4 the same code snippet returns the error:

> 'range' object has no attribute 'append'

What is the reason for this error in Python 3.3.4, and what is the solution?

The desired output: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 200].

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In Python2, `range` returns a list.

In Python3, `range` returns a [range object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges).
The range object does not have an append method. To fix, convert the range object to a list:

```
>>> myrange = list(range(10,100,10))
>>> myrange.append(200)
>>> myrange
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 200]
```

The range object is a lazy sequence. It purposefully avoids forming a list of all the values since this requires more memory, and often people use `range` simply to keep track of a counter -- a usage which does not require holding the full list in memory at once.

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges):

> The advantage of the range type over a regular list or tuple is that a
> range object will always take the same (small) amount of memory, no
> matter the size of the range it represents (as it only stores the
> start, stop and step values, calculating individual items and
> subranges as needed).

Comment: A `range` object is *not* an iterator, this is easily verified by trying `next(range(10))`

Comment: A `range` objects is *iterable*, which means you can use `iter(range(10))` to *get* an iterator (in CPython, an object of type `range_iterator`).

Answer (score 12):

Check [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22437321/2334951)'s answer to know why you can't append to a `range()`.

However, keep `range()`-s iterating approach by using `itertools.chain()` instead of forcing it to a list and appending to it then. It is faster and more efficient.

```
from itertools import chain
c = chain(range(10,100,10), [200])
print(list(c))
# [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 200]
```

Note:
Here `list(c)` also forced the `chain` object and was used only for representation. Use the `chain` object in a `for` loop instead.